# loopback how to customize authentication

Tags: loopbackjs

I am setting up a microservice application where each microservice is an independent loopback application, and one of this microservice is the gateway which holds user accounts and accessToken models. all the other microservice should query the gateway if they need to validate an AccessToken.

if authentication is enabled I understand loopback does an AccessToken.findByid to initialize the AccessContext with the token information so we can authorize the requests.
In my case the loopback app does not own the AccessToken model and as expected it fails with following error:

```
{   "error": {
        "statusCode": 500,
        "name": "Error",
        "message": "Cannot call AccessToken.findById(). The findById method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!",
}
```

My question is: what is the best way to override the AccessToken lookup so that it queries the gateway microservice instead?

Answer (score 1):

In each microservices you need atach your AccessToken to gateway db. Try something like this:

```
app.loopback.AccessToken.attachTo(app.datasources.db); // db <-- gateway dataSource
app.model(app.loopback.AccessToken);
```